# How can I send a private message to another user using android facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook

I have searched on internet, but I have not found a solution for my problem. 
In my app I have an option for a Facebook using the android Facebook `sdk`, then I get the information of user  ***Facebook(accessToken, userId)*** say `USER1`. Is there any way to send a private message to another user say `USER2` who is not a friend of `USER1`.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook SDK doesn't contain any private message feature till date.they haven't included it due to some spam flaws.the only way you can do that use [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) , though I haven't tried it.give a try.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", "user_id");
params.putString("name", "tittle");
params.putString("link", "url"); // this link param is required

facebook.dialog(context, "send", params, new DialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
       ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {}
});
```

Comment: Hello, Does anyone tried it or find a solution to achieve this ?

Thanks